# input type text and email behaving differently inside angular directive (Two way databinding)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm not getting how to over come the following situation, I have a directive with two scope passed from parent as "=" denoting the model binding say `attr1` and `attr2` are those values.

Inside directive I have used both in the interpolation `{{attr1}}` and `{{attr2}}`, Also I have used it inside input type text and email as models.

When I change the value of attr1 from textbox the value gets reflected in the interpolation `{{attr1}}`, but the change in `attr2` textbox is not reflected in the interpolation `{{attr2}}` , although it gets binded when an valid email id is entered, but i need to show the email when its being typed.

Is there any work around for this ?

How can I do it ?

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/ex1htj83/4/).

```
app.directive("myDirective", function(){

return {
    restrict: "EA",
    //replace:true,
    //transclude:true,
    scope: {
        attr1: "=",
        attr2: "="
    },
    template: [
        "<div>attr1 : {{attr1}}</div>",
        "<div>attr2 : {{attr2}}</div>",
        "attr1 : <input type='text' ng-model='attr1' /><br/>",
        "attr2 : <input type='email' ng-model='attr2' /><br/>",
        ].join(""),

};
```

Thanks,

Vinod Louis

Answer (score 0):

Sir this is the problem of html 5 email validation until and unless you enter correct email format you will not be shown the typed field as html 5 type email has validation format a@b.c something like this. and one more thing is in your code you have written my-directive and in directive you written myDirective. I have solved this problem please try entering any valid email format in your email field. Actually ng-biding is happening but when you enter email  format correctly the text will be visible.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ex1htj83/7/)

Here is my code
html

```
<div ng-app="app">
 <name attr1="Sudarshan"  attr2="sud@gmail.com"></name>
</div>
```

ng-code

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.directive("name", function(){
     return {
        restrict: "E",
        link:function(scope,e,a){
            scope.att1=a.attr1;
            scope.att2=a.attr2;
         },
       template: 
            ["<div>attr1 : {{att1}}</div>",
            "<div>attr2 : {{att2}}</div>",
            "attr1 : <input type='text' ng-model='att1' /><br/>",
            "attr2 : <input type='email' ng-model='att2' /><br/>"].join(""),
 };
});
```

Comment: yeah i do know that it becomes visible when correct email is entered, but i need to show the email while its being typed, in the fiddle i posted in my question if you enter a valid email you can see the model binded

Comment: Binding doesn't work with input type="email" #1426 this is the issue with angular.js you can see in github https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1426 still not it solved but the best answer is you need to validate in directive. also i seen in angular docs there also email doesn't shows until valid email is entered.This is how angular works.

Comment: Still if you want to show binding then you can use jquery to show email typing live here is the example. http://jsfiddle.net/nt7Gr/3/